# Visual Studio 2013 - Form "Live" preview

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-forms-designer

Is there any possibility to show our Form without starting debug?
I know there is designer preview, but I want to perform a quick test of form apperance (all of the popups, lists etc.) without building and debugging applicattion. The problem is when I add new form to existing application that has to log-in to external system - which takes time.

Comment: I am missing that functionality too. I think Netbeans has it and it's useful. We should be able to write a plugin for Vs that does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always build the new form in a separate solution and copy it over once you are happy with its performance/operation. That way you only need to compile the form and not the entire other project w/ login etc...

Comment: This is very unhandy especially when joining into an exiting application. Then you have dependencies into other code. How you copy the form?